# How to use the InputValidator from sweetalert2 within angular 6 project?

Tags: html, angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to do the following thing:

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Merge" [swal]="{
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    input: 'text', inputPlaceholder: 'Please type the description in',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-outline-primary',
    inputValidator: (value) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (value.length >= 3) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                resolve('The description should be at least 3 characters!')
            }
        });
        }
    }">
    <mat-icon>call_merge</mat-icon>
</button>
```

As you can see, I have here one button and [sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2) stuff. When user presses the button, a window appears with a text box. This text field must contain at least 3 characters, otherwise the user will see an error message from sweetalert.

The problem is: The Angular compiler is not happy with the `inputValidator`. The compiler always says that somewhere in the lambda expression of `inputValidator` a parenthesis is missing. However, if I delete `inputValidator`, the code works.

I also tried to define the swal components separately, such as

```html
<swal
    #MergeSwal
    title="Are you sure?"
    type="warning"
    input="text"
    inputPlaceholder="Please type the description in"
    [showCancelButton]="true"
    confirmButtonText="Yes"
    cancelButtonText="Cancel"
    confirmButtonClass="btn btn-primary"
    cancelButtonClass="btn btn-outline-primary"
    (inputValidator)="validate($event)">
    </swal>
```

with a validate function

```js
validate(event) {
    console.log('It works');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (event.length >= 3) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            resolve('The description should be at least 3 characters!')
        }
      });
}
```

and with this code for the button

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Merge" [swal]="MergeSwal">
     <mat-icon>call_merge</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In this case, the sweetalert window is displayed correctly, but the validator does not work. The `validate(...)` function is not executed for some reason.

I also tried to define the function

```js
merge() {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        input: 'text',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Please type the description in',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-outline-primary',
        inputValidator: (value) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (value.length >= 3) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                resolve('The description should be at least 3 characters!')
            }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Then I call this function when the button is pressed

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Merge" (click)="merge()">
    <mat-icon>call_merge</mat-icon>
</button>
```

In this case, everything works well except the `.css` classes. The necessary error message is displayed, but the Angular compiler obviously does not see any `.css` classes defined in the `.ts` file. As a result, the sweetalet window is displayed with standard `.css` classes.

What is the easiest way to force the `inputValidator` to work properly?

Comment: Please create one stackblitz of your code.

Comment: Done: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckhee3

In the app.component.html, delete everything from line 25 to line 35 inclusive. I left this inputValidator code in the file to show that the compiler is missing some parentheses. 
Only the code connected to the third key works. However, only the .css standard classes are used there. My project uses its own .css classes, which are included as node-module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

In my `.ts` file:

```js
import { SwalComponent } from '@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2';
...
@ViewChild('mergeDialogSwal') private mergeDialogSwal: SwalComponent;
...
mergeDialogValidator(): void {
    if (this.mergeDialogSwal === undefined) { return; }
    this.mergeDialogSwal.inputValidator = (value) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (value.length >= 3) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          resolve('The description should be at least 3 characters!');
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

In my `.html` file:

```html
<swal #mergeDialogSwal 
      title="Do you really want to merge the batches?"
      text="You can not undo this action!"
      type="warning"
      input="text"
      inputPlaceholder="Specify a description for the merged batch" 
      [showCancelButton]="true"
      confirmButtonText="Yes, merge"
      cancelButtonText="Cancel"
      confirmButtonClass="btn btn-primary"
      cancelButtonClass="btn btn-outline-primary" 
      [inputValidator]="mergeDialogValidator()"
      (confirm)="mergeBatches()">
</swal>
...
<button (click)="mergeDialogSwal.show()">Click Me</button>
```

Maybe this solution is not quite good, but I have no other idea. If someone can suggest a better solution, I would be happy.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhdv9z

Answer (score 1):

#### In Component html

```html
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Merge" [swal]="MergeSwal">
     <mat-icon>call_merge</mat-icon>
</button>
```

```js
<swal #MergeSwal  

      // all other options 

      [inputValidator]="mergeSwalValidator" >
</swal>
```

#### In Component ts

```
public mergeSwalValidator(value: string): string | null {
    if (value.length >= 3) {
          return null;
    } else {
          return 'The description should be at least 3 characters!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * Validate Swal Component to make sure
 * reason is required before submitting
 *
 * @param {string} value
 * @returns {Promise<string | null>}
 */
requiredReason = (value) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(value ? null : 'You need to write something!'));
}
```

```html
<swal #deleteMultipleSwal 
      title="Enter Reason" 
      input="textarea" 
      [inputValidator]="requiredReason" 
      inputPlaceholder="Nothing" 
      [showCancelButton]="true"
      [text]="'Only items created in the last 2 hours will be deleted'"
      [focusCancel]="true" 
      (confirm)="enqueueMultipleDeletions($event)">
</swal>
```